# Ошибка при изменении файла react - ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, warning

Первый раз использую TS. столкнулся с такой проблемой что при запуске npm start все ок - проект собирается и ошибок нет, но только стоит что - то изменить в проекте
получаю данную ошибку `node.params is not iterable Occurred while linting /Users/....../ContentHomePage.tsx:1 Rule: "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars"` второй день обнимаю проект, но только 0)

---

Еще при разработке получаю данный ворнинг: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
ESLint: Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'interface'. (10:0)
```

но вроде проект собирается.
Может кто сталкивался, буду благодарен любому совету.

Eslint...

```js
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "ignorePatterns": ["node_modules", "dist", "build"],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "requireConfigFile" : false,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "prettier", "import", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "indent": ["off"],
    "no-unused-vars" : "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars" : [ "error" ],
    "linebreak-style": [0, "unix"],
    "quotes": ["error", "single"],
    "semi": ["off"],
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "import/no-unresolved": [2, { "caseSensitive": false }],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"] }],
    "import/order": [
      2,
      {
        "groups": ["builtin", "external", "internal", "parent", "sibling", "index"],
        "newlines-between": "always"
      }
    ]
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "src/"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Вероятнее всего дело в свойстве parser. Попробуйте использовать https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/parser

Comment: Действительно, вылечил используя:
$ npm i --save-dev typescript @typescript-eslint/parser
и заменой в  eslint
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо изменить в файле `eslint` свойство `parser` для работы с TypeScript используя следующий пакет:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/parser